# Raspberry Pi3 - Omnikey 5022 - PCSC_SCAN - SCardEstablishContext: Service not available

Tags: raspberry-pi3, rfid, pcsc

I am using the rfid reader Hid Omnikey 5022 on my Raspberry3. i installed :
- libsystemd-dev
- libudev-dev
- pcsc-lite-1.8.25
- libusb-1.0.22
- ccid-1.4.31
- pcsc-tools-1.5.4
- libpcsclite-dev
- libccid
- libpcsc-perl

This reader is supported with the CCID driver
https://ccid.apdu.fr/ccid/supported.html

when i try the command : `pcsc_scan`
it returns the error : `SCardEstablishContext: Service not available`

when i use : `strace pcsc_scan`
it returns :

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/Downloads# strace pcsc_scan
execve("/usr/local/bin/pcsc_scan", ["pcsc_scan"], [/* 59 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x6ec000
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="raspberrypi", ...}) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x76f0d000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.preload", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=42, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 42, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x76f0c000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\210\5\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 20868, SEEK_SET)               = 20868
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1000) = 1000
lseek(3, 20540, SEEK_SET)               = 20540
read(3, "A,\0\0\0aeabi\0\1\"\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\3\f\1\22\4\24"..., 45) = 45
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=21868, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 86080, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x76eca000
mprotect(0x76ecf000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x76ede000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x4000) = 0x76ede000
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x76f0c000, 42)                  = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=82593, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 82593, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x76eb5000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpcsclite.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\360\21\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 33124, SEEK_SET)               = 33124
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1000) = 1000
lseek(3, 32801, SEEK_SET)               = 32801
read(3, "A,\0\0\0aeabi\0\1\"\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 45) = 45
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=34124, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 101576, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x76e9c000
mprotect(0x76ea4000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x76eb3000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x7000) = 0x76eb3000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0dI\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 125740, SEEK_SET)              = 125740
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1560) = 1560
lseek(3, 90536, SEEK_SET)               = 90536
read(3, "A.\0\0\0aeabi\0\1$\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\23\1\24"..., 47) = 47
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=127300, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 164432, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x76e73000
mprotect(0x76e89000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x76e98000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x15000) = 0x76e98000
mmap2(0x76e9a000, 4688, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x76e9a000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0@h\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 1231820, SEEK_SET)             = 1231820
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 2880) = 2880
lseek(3, 1228284, SEEK_SET)             = 1228284
read(3, "A.\0\0\0aeabi\0\1$\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\23\1\24"..., 47) = 47
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1234700, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1303872, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x76d34000
mprotect(0x76e5d000, 65536, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x76e6d000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x129000) = 0x76e6d000
mmap2(0x76e70000, 9536, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x76e70000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0P\t\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 8680, SEEK_SET)                = 8680
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1120) = 1120
lseek(3, 8328, SEEK_SET)                = 8328
read(3, "A.\0\0\0aeabi\0\1$\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\23\1\24"..., 47) = 47
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9800, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 73912, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x76d21000
mprotect(0x76d23000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x76d32000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x76d32000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0 \27\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 25352, SEEK_SET)               = 25352
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1280) = 1280
lseek(3, 24940, SEEK_SET)               = 24940
read(3, "A.\0\0\0aeabi\0\1$\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\23\1\24"..., 47) = 47
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=26632, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 90640, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x76d0a000
mprotect(0x76d10000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x76d1f000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5000) = 0x76d1f000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x76f0b000
set_tls(0x76f0b980, 0x76f0c058, 0x76f11050, 0x76f0b980, 0x76f11050) = 0
mprotect(0x76e6d000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x76e98000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x76d1f000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x76d32000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x76eb3000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x76eca000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
mprotect(0x76eca000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC) = 0
cacheflush(0x76eca000, 0x76ecf000, 0, 0x15, 0) = 0
mprotect(0x76ede000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x22000, 4096, PROT_READ)      = 0
mprotect(0x76f10000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0x76eb5000, 82593)               = 0
set_tid_address(0x76f0b528)             = 3210
set_robust_list(0x76f0b530, 12)         = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0x76e772b0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x76d606c0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x76e77390, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x76d606c0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
ugetrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x11ea8, sa_mask=[INT], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x76d606b0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
stat64("/var/run/pcscd/pcscd.comm", {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0666, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x6ec000
brk(0x70d000)                           = 0x70d000
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/pcscd/pcscd.comm"}, 28) = 0
fcntl64(3, F_GETFL)                     = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl64(3, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)  = 0
_newselect(4, NULL, [3], NULL, NULL)    = 1 (out [3])
send(3, "\f\0\0\0\21\0\0\0", 8, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 8
_newselect(4, NULL, [3], NULL, NULL)    = 1 (out [3])
send(3, "\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 12, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 12
_newselect(4, [3], NULL, NULL, NULL)    = 1 (in [3])
read(3, "\4\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\35\0\20\200", 12) = 12
ioctl(2, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
write(2, "\33[31mSCardEstablishContext: Serv"..., 55SCardEstablishContext: Service not available.
) = 55
exit_group(-1)                          = ?
+++ exited with 255 +++
```

the pcscd seems to work :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pcscd -f -d
00000000 [1996378896] debuglog.c:299:DebugLogSetLevel() debug level=debug
00000258 [1996378896] utils.c:82:GetDaemonPid() Can't open /var/run/pcscd/pcscd.pid: No such file or directory
00000468 [1996378896] configfile.l:360:DBGetReaderList() Parsing conf file: /usr/local/etc/reader.conf.d
00000065 [1996378896] pcscdaemon.c:662:main() pcsc-lite 1.8.25 daemon ready.
00026608 [1996378896] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x1D6B, PID: 0x0002, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/001
00000885 [1996378896] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x1D6B, PID: 0x0002, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/001
00000898 [1996378896] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0424, PID: 0x2514, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/002
00000968 [1996378896] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0424, PID: 0x2514, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/003
00001066 [1996378896] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0424, PID: 0x7800, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/007
00000956 [1996378896] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0424, PID: 0x2514, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/003
00000911 [1996378896] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0461, PID: 0x4D64, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/004
00000945 [1996378896] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0424, PID: 0x2514, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/003
00000951 [1996378896] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0749, PID: 0x1000, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/006
00000939 [1996378896] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0749, PID: 0x1000, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/006
00000958 [1996378896] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0424, PID: 0x2514, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/003
00000978 [1996378896] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0424, PID: 0x2514, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/002
00000954 [1996378896] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x076B, PID: 0x5022, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/022
00000069 [1996378896] hotplug_libudev.c:440:HPAddDevice() Adding USB device: HID Global OMNIKEY 5022 Smart Card Reader
00000416 [1996378896] readerfactory.c:1075:RFInitializeReader() Attempting startup of HID Global OMNIKEY 5022 Smart Card Reader [OMNIKEY 5022 Smart Card Reader] (KJ-13171286-1904-000290) 00 00 using /usr/local/lib/pcsc/drivers/ifd-ccid.bundle/Contents/Linux/libccid.so
00001033 [1996378896] readerfactory.c:950:RFBindFunctions() Loading IFD Handler 3.0
00000202 [1996378896] ifdhandler.c:1961:init_driver() Driver version: 1.4.31
00006743 [1996378896] ifdhandler.c:1978:init_driver() LogLevel: 0x0003
00000071 [1996378896] ifdhandler.c:1989:init_driver() DriverOptions: 0x0000
00001321 [1996378896] ifdhandler.c:110:CreateChannelByNameOrChannel() Lun: 0, device: usb:076b/5022:libudev:0:/dev/bus/usb/001/022
00000102 [1996378896] ccid_usb.c:302:OpenUSBByName() Using: /usr/local/lib/pcsc/drivers/ifd-ccid.bundle/Contents/Info.plist
00006736 [1996378896] ccid_usb.c:320:OpenUSBByName() ifdManufacturerString: Ludovic Rousseau (ludovic.rousseau@free.fr)
00000046 [1996378896] ccid_usb.c:321:OpenUSBByName() ifdProductString: Generic CCID driver
00000033 [1996378896] ccid_usb.c:322:OpenUSBByName() Copyright: This driver is protected by terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1, or (at your option) any later version.
00095750 [1996378896] ccid_usb.c:660:OpenUSBByName() Found Vendor/Product: 076B/5022 (HID Global OMNIKEY 5022 Smart Card Reader)
00000036 [1996378896] ccid_usb.c:662:OpenUSBByName() Using USB bus/device: 1/22
00000016 [1996378896] ccid_usb.c:722:OpenUSBByName() bNumDataRatesSupported is 0
00111362 [1996378896] ifdhandler.c:381:IFDHGetCapabilities() tag: 0xFB3, usb:076b/5022:libudev:0:/dev/bus/usb/001/022 (lun: 0)
00000035 [1996378896] readerfactory.c:396:RFAddReader() Using the reader polling thread
00000957 [1974453120] ifdhandler.c:1154:IFDHPowerICC() action: PowerUp, usb:076b/5022:libudev:0:/dev/bus/usb/001/022 (lun: 0)
00014077 [1974453120] eventhandler.c:289:EHStatusHandlerThread() powerState: POWER_STATE_POWERED
00000006 [1996378896] ifdhandler.c:381:IFDHGetCapabilities() tag: 0xFAE, usb:076b/5022:libudev:0:/dev/bus/usb/001/022 (lun: 0)
00000036 [1996378896] ifdhandler.c:476:IFDHGetCapabilities() Reader supports 1 slot(s)
00000047 [1974453120] Card ATR: 3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 0B 00 14 00 00 00 00 77 
00000702 [1996378896] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0424, PID: 0x2514, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/002
00000387 [1996378896] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0B05, PID: 0x7774, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/021
00000366 [1996378896] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0B05, PID: 0x7774, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/021
00000385 [1996378896] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0424, PID: 0x2514, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/002
00905718 [1974453120] ifdhandler.c:1154:IFDHPowerICC() action: PowerDown, usb:076b/5022:libudev:0:/dev/bus/usb/001/022 (lun: 0)
00033069 [1974453120] eventhandler.c:482:EHStatusHandlerThread() powerState: POWER_STATE_UNPOWERED
```

When pcscd run, i used : `sudo pcsc_scan`
 the pcscd log is (see the lines beginning with '***'):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents $ sudo pcscd -f -d
00000000 [1995817744] debuglog.c:299:DebugLogSetLevel() debug level=debug
00000814 [1995817744] configfile.l:360:DBGetReaderList() Parsing conf file: /usr/local/etc/reader.conf.d
00000165 [1995817744] pcscdaemon.c:662:main() pcsc-lite 1.8.25 daemon ready.
00031408 [1995817744] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x1D6B, PID: 0x0002, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/001
00001259 [1995817744] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x1D6B, PID: 0x0002, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/001
00001041 [1995817744] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0424, PID: 0x2514, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/002
00001051 [1995817744] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0424, PID: 0x2514, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/003
00001098 [1995817744] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0424, PID: 0x7800, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/007
00001096 [1995817744] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0424, PID: 0x2514, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/003
00001022 [1995817744] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0461, PID: 0x4D64, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/004
00001046 [1995817744] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0424, PID: 0x2514, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/003
00001009 [1995817744] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0749, PID: 0x1000, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/006
00001003 [1995817744] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0749, PID: 0x1000, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/006
00001038 [1995817744] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0424, PID: 0x2514, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/003
00001001 [1995817744] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0424, PID: 0x2514, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/002
00000955 [1995817744] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x076B, PID: 0x5022, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/024
00000143 [1995817744] hotplug_libudev.c:440:HPAddDevice() Adding USB device: HID Global OMNIKEY 5022 Smart Card Reader
00000489 [1995817744] readerfactory.c:1075:RFInitializeReader() Attempting startup of HID Global OMNIKEY 5022 Smart Card Reader [OMNIKEY 5022 Smart Card Reader] (KJ-13171286-1904-000290) 00 00 using /usr/local/lib/pcsc/drivers/ifd-ccid.bundle/Contents/Linux/libccid.so
00001091 [1995817744] readerfactory.c:950:RFBindFunctions() Loading IFD Handler 3.0
00000413 [1995817744] ifdhandler.c:1961:init_driver() Driver version: 1.4.31
00006619 [1995817744] ifdhandler.c:1978:init_driver() LogLevel: 0x0003
00000131 [1995817744] ifdhandler.c:1989:init_driver() DriverOptions: 0x0000
00001393 [1995817744] ifdhandler.c:110:CreateChannelByNameOrChannel() Lun: 0, device: usb:076b/5022:libudev:0:/dev/bus/usb/001/024
00000176 [1995817744] ccid_usb.c:302:OpenUSBByName() Using: /usr/local/lib/pcsc/drivers/ifd-ccid.bundle/Contents/Info.plist
00019948 [1995817744] ccid_usb.c:320:OpenUSBByName() ifdManufacturerString: Ludovic Rousseau (ludovic.rousseau@free.fr)
00000114 [1995817744] ccid_usb.c:321:OpenUSBByName() ifdProductString: Generic CCID driver
00000032 [1995817744] ccid_usb.c:322:OpenUSBByName() Copyright: This driver is protected by terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1, or (at your option) any later version.
00112071 [1995817744] ccid_usb.c:660:OpenUSBByName() Found Vendor/Product: 076B/5022 (HID Global OMNIKEY 5022 Smart Card Reader)
00000035 [1995817744] ccid_usb.c:662:OpenUSBByName() Using USB bus/device: 1/24
00000027 [1995817744] ccid_usb.c:722:OpenUSBByName() bNumDataRatesSupported is 0
00015695 [1995817744] ifdhandler.c:381:IFDHGetCapabilities() tag: 0xFB3, usb:076b/5022:libudev:0:/dev/bus/usb/001/024 (lun: 0)
00000038 [1995817744] readerfactory.c:396:RFAddReader() Using the reader polling thread
00001081 [1973891968] ifdhandler.c:1154:IFDHPowerICC() action: PowerUp, usb:076b/5022:libudev:0:/dev/bus/usb/001/024 (lun: 0)
00014151 [1973891968] eventhandler.c:289:EHStatusHandlerThread() powerState: POWER_STATE_POWERED
00000003 [1995817744] ifdhandler.c:381:IFDHGetCapabilities() tag: 0xFAE, usb:076b/5022:libudev:0:/dev/bus/usb/001/024 (lun: 0)
00000074 [1973891968] Card ATR: 3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 0B 00 14 00 00 00 00 77 
00000040 [1995817744] ifdhandler.c:476:IFDHGetCapabilities() Reader supports 1 slot(s)
00000916 [1995817744] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0424, PID: 0x2514, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/002
00000463 [1995817744] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0B05, PID: 0x7774, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/021
00000415 [1995817744] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0B05, PID: 0x7774, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/021
00000432 [1995817744] hotplug_libudev.c:301:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0424, PID: 0x2514, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/002
00094258 [1973891968] ifdhandler.c:1154:IFDHPowerICC() action: PowerDown, usb:076b/5022:libudev:0:/dev/bus/usb/001/024 (lun: 0)
00034057 [1973891968] eventhandler.c:482:EHStatusHandlerThread() powerState: POWER_STATE_UNPOWERED
17658438 [1995817744] winscard_msg_srv.c:255:ProcessEventsServer() Common channel packet arrival
00000116 [1995817744] winscard_msg_srv.c:267:ProcessEventsServer() ProcessCommonChannelRequest detects: 14
00000033 [1995817744] pcscdaemon.c:133:SVCServiceRunLoop() A new context thread creation is requested: 14
***00000229 [1955591040] winscard_svc.c:340:ContextThread() Authorized PC/SC client
***00000039 [1955591040] winscard_svc.c:344:ContextThread() Thread is started: dwClientID=14, threadContext @0x14208d8
***00000051 [1955591040] winscard_svc.c:362:ContextThread() Received command: CMD_VERSION from client 14
***00000064 [1955591040] winscard_svc.c:374:ContextThread() Client is protocol version 4:3
***00000026 [1955591040] winscard_svc.c:383:ContextThread() Client protocol is 4:3
***00000025 [1955591040] winscard_svc.c:385:ContextThread() Server protocol is 4:4
***00000025 [1955591040] winscard_svc.c:394:ContextThread() CMD_VERSION rv=0x8010001D for client 14
***00000794 [1955591040] winscard_svc.c:354:ContextThread() Client die: 14
***00000074 [1955591040] winscard_svc.c:1055:MSGCleanupClient() Thread is stopping: dwClientID=14, threadContext @0x14208d8
***00000028 [1955591040] winscard_svc.c:1061:MSGCleanupClient() Freeing SCONTEXT @0x14208d8
07054799 [1973891968] eventhandler.c:358:EHStatusHandlerThread() Card Removed From HID Global OMNIKEY 5022 Smart Card Reader [OMNIKEY 5022 Smart Card Reader] (KJ-13171286-1904-000290) 00 00
02336437 [1973891968] ifdhandler.c:1154:IFDHPowerICC() action: PowerUp, usb:076b/5022:libudev:0:/dev/bus/usb/001/024 (lun: 0)
00014370 [1973891968] eventhandler.c:406:EHStatusHandlerThread() powerState: POWER_STATE_POWERED
00000070 [1973891968] eventhandler.c:423:EHStatusHandlerThread() Card inserted into HID Global OMNIKEY 5022 Smart Card Reader [OMNIKEY 5022 Smart Card Reader] (KJ-13171286-1904-000290) 00 00
00000102 [1973891968] Card ATR: 3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 0B 00 14 00 00 00 00 77 
00593095 [1973891968] eventhandler.c:482:EHStatusHandlerThread() powerState: POWER_STATE_UNPOWERED
00000501 [1973891968] eventhandler.c:358:EHStatusHandlerThread() Card Removed From HID Global OMNIKEY 5022 Smart Card Reader [OMNIKEY 5022 Smart Card Reader] (KJ-13171286-1904-000290) 00 00
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Is `pcscd` running?

Comment: yes. i put the log of pcscd in my post above.Thank you

Comment: And is `pcscd` running while you run `pcsc_scan`?

Comment: yes, i put the pcscd log when calling 'pcsc_scan' in my post above (see lines starting with '***'). Thank you

Comment: Does it do the same with version 1.8.24 of packages `libpcsclite1`, `pcsc-lite` and `pcscd`? Trying the previous version (1.4.30) of `ccid` and `libccid` might be worth trying as well...I see that those packages were updated recently (10-Aug-2019), but `pcsc-tools` was not updated...Good luck!